# Programming error: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to run the following in python 2.7(windows) and it gives me an error:

> ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
>   text_factory that can interpret 8-bit byte strings (like text_factory
>   = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8-*-

import sqlite3;
db = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO X(id,a,b) VALUES(?,?,?)', (999998,"ą---ź---ć---ó---ęĘ","ssf"))
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM X where id = 999998')
for row in cursor:
    print row

db.commit()
db.close()
```

How can I insert those kind of strings("ąźć" = polish signs) into my sqlite database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could follow their recommendation: "just switch your application to Unicode strings."

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO X(id,a,b) VALUES(?,?,?)',
    (999998,u"ą---ź---ć---ó---ęĘ","ssf"))
```

Note the `u` before the string literal. This makes it a unicode literal instead.

Comment: This gives me another error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: B9 is not the character you've pasted into your sample. I infer that you have the wrong encoding listed in your `encoding` " statement. Or, if you prefer, your text editor saved the file with the wrong encoding. In either event, the encoding you actually have and what you claim to have don't match.

Comment: The encoding your file actually uses appears to be [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)

Comment: Try either convincing your text editor to save the file in utf-8, or try changing the encoding line to `# -*- encoding: windows-1250`.

Comment: When I change this line: # -*- encoding: Windows-1250-*- it gives me this: ╣---č---Š---ˇ---ŕ╩. Btw. I thought that the # -*- encoding: utf-8-*- sets the encoding of the file to utf-8. Am I correct?

Comment: "*it gives me this*" What gives you that?

Comment: The "*encoding: utf-8*" line doesn't so much set the encoding of the file as inform Python (and possibly other tools) what the encoding already is. Since your file wasn't utf-8-encoded, Python got confused when it said it was.

Comment: Ok. I think I've changed the encoding in notepad++ to utf-8(at least in the bottom right corner it says so) and when I run the program in cmd using python test.py the output is (999987, '\xc4\x85---\xc5\xba---\xc4\x87---\xc3\xb3---\xc4\x99\xc4\x98', 'ssf') with the # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*- at the top of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75336/discussion-between-rob-and-user3142434).

Answer (score 2):

For starters, have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

That is, `db.text_factory = str` right after the `connect`.

Comment: When I add that I get the following output : "(999998, '\xb9---\x9f---\xe6---\xf3---\xea\xca', 'ssf')"

Comment: @user3142434 That is just Python's representation of what your data looks like encoded as UTF-8. See the table at https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals . It's one of those weird behaviours of Python 2, caused by trying to print a tuple. If you just print ``row[1]``, which is a string, it should show up as proper characters.

Comment: Ok. There is no error now, but the output is not what expected: ╣---č---Š---ˇ---ŕ╩

Comment: Refer to the comments on Rob's answer. You're not saving the file you keep your code in as UTF-8.